# Sorting Array AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, sorting

I´d like to sort this array:

['Ramsey', 'Sephora', 'seq', 'ser', 'user']

Like this:

If I type "Se" it sorts the array so the strings containing "se" (lower or uppercase) comes first in the array.

How could I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically they all contain "se", so you don't need to sort :)

If you want to remove all elements that don't contain "se", you can call `filter()` on your Array before: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html#filter()

then just sort alphabetically as normal. You might want to create your own filter as `filter()` creates a new Array each time.

If you want to keep the objects in the array, then you'll need to implement your own sorting. Something like this should work:

```
public function Test() 
{
    var a:Array = ['Ramsey', 'Sephora', 'seq', 'ser', 'user'];
    trace( a ); // Ramsey,Sephora,seq,ser,user
    a.sort( this._sort );
    trace( a ); // Sephora,seq,ser,user,Ramsey
}

private function _sort( a:String, b:String ):int
{
    // if they're the same we don't care
    if ( a == b )
        return 0;

    // make them both lowercase
    var aLower:String = a.toLowerCase();
    var bLower:String = b.toLowerCase();

    // see if they contain our string
    var aIndex:int = aLower.indexOf( "se" );
    var bIndex:int = bLower.indexOf( "se" );

    // if one of them doesn't have it, set it afterwards
    if ( aIndex == -1 && bIndex != -1 ) // a doesn't contain our string
        return 1; // b before a
    else if ( aIndex != -1 && bIndex == -1 ) // b doesn't contain our string
        return -1; // a before b
    else if ( aIndex == -1 && bIndex == -1 ) // neither contain our string
        return ( aLower < bLower ) ? -1 : 1; // sort them alphabetically
    else
    {
        // they both have "se"
        // if a has "se" before b, set it in front
        // otherwise if they're in the same place, sort alphabetically, or on
        // length or any other way we want
        if ( aIndex == bIndex )
            return ( aLower < bLower ) ? -1 : 1;
        return aIndex - bIndex;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var array:Array = ['Ramsey', 'Sephora', 'seq', 'ser', 'user'];

trace( array.sort(Array.CASEINSENSITIVE) );
```